# Como acrescentar linhas em um data.frame e ou tabela no shinyserver?

Tags: r, data.frame, shiny, render

Olá, boa noite!
estou tentando resolver algumas coisas pelo `shiny`, porém me deparei com um problema, preciso criar um `data.frame`, onde eu seja capaz de acrescentar linhas de informação, sem ficar fazendo a logística de usar `write.table()` vs `read.table`.

```
library(shiny)



ui<-fluidPage(
sidebarPanel(
fluidRow(
selectInput("INPUT",  label="Entrada:"  ,choices=list("",1,2,3,4,5,6,7)),
selectInput("NOMEIPT", label="Nome:", choices=list("","Área","Comprimento","Largura")),
selectInput("COLOUR", label="Cor:",  choices=list("","black","white","red","green","blue","brown","yellow")),
actionButton("ADDIN",label="adicionar"))),
            mainPanel(fluidPage(
              fluidRow(tableOutput("dados")))))

server1 <- function(session,input, output) {

  counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # tentei gerar um valor reativo, para criar vários data.frames
    observeEvent(input$ADDIN,{

counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1 })

  eventReactive(input$ADDIN,{
    # nesse caso deveria a cada vez que eu selecionace as três, opções, e clicasse no botão "Adicionar"
    # ele deveria gerar um data.frame: df1<-data.frame(iten=..cor=..nome=..) para cada click df2...df3...df4..
    eval(parse(text=paste("df",as.numeric(input$INPUT),"<-data.frame(iten=",as.numeric(input$INPUT),',cor="',input$COLOUR,'",nome=',input$NOMEIPT,")",sep="")))
      })


  # depois seria necessário apenas juntar esses data.frame usando o rbind, ou rbind.data.frame, não sei a diferença dos dois.
  # porém , eu não sei porque cargas d'água os data.frames não ficam armazenados... até pensei em colocar eles dentro da sessão, porém como eles usar entradas reativas
  # "input$.....", não iria funcionar.....

  DFrame<-eventReactive(input$ADDIN,{
    eval(parse(text=paste(c("rbind(",rep("",counter$countervalue-1)),"df",1:counter$countervalue,c(rep(",",counter$countervalue-1),")"),sep="")))

  })


  output$dados<-renderTable({DFrame()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server1)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Também tentei criar uum objeto reativo, e acrescentar a ele um data.frame vazio:

server2 <- function(session,input, output) {
  DT<-reactiveValues(DT=NULL)


  observeEvent(input$ADDIN,{

    DT$DT<-data.frame(iten=NULL,cor=NULL,nome=NULL)
  })

  DFrame<-eventReactive(input$ADDIN,{

  rbind.data.frame(DT$DT,data.frame(iten=as.numeric(input$INPUT),cor=input$COLOUR,nome=input$NOMEIPT))
 })

 output$dados<-renderTable({DFrame()})

}

shinyApp(ui,server2)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# tentei dessa forma adicionando linhas ao data.frame vazio

  server3 <- function(session,input, output) {
    DT<-reactiveValues(DT=NULL)


    observeEvent(input$ADDIN,{

      DT$DT<-data.frame(iten="",cor="",nome="")
    })

eventReactive(input$ADDIN,{

  DT$DT[as.numeric(input$INPUT),]<-data.frame(iten=as.numeric(input$INPUT),cor=input$COLOUR,nome=input$NOMEIPT)

})

output$dados<-renderTable({DT$DT})

  }



  shinyApp(ui,server3)
```

O que eu preciso é que ele gere um `data.frame(iten=..,cor=..,nome=..)`, e a medida que eu selecione as opções e click em adicionar, ele armazene e carregue a informação, e cada mudança de opções, ao clicar em adicionar, ele acrescente uma nova linha ao data.frame com as novas informações... eu preciso disso pois usarei como os itens do data.frame para gerenciar, os nomes e cores que irei usar nos kml files que irei carregar.... por isso não queria ficar regravando tabela pelo `write.table()`, e `read.table()`... pois cada arquivo novo geraria uma tabela nova!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INTRODUÇÃO**

Vou apresentar a solução do problema utilizando o [reactValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/reactiveValues.html). **Entretanto** leia as considerações que vou fazer sobre essa solução logo em seguida.

**SOLUÇÃO**

A solução é essa:

1. crie um data.frame vazio no arquivo app.R, fora do ui e do server.
2. crie um reactValue para o data.frame criado.
3. atualize o data.frame a partir dos inputs sempre que o botão é clicado

Aqui vai o código completo do app.R

```
library(shiny)

## Cria data.frame vazio só para começar
df <- data.frame(Entrada=character(),
                 Nome=character(), 
                 Cor=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Interface que não foi alterada
ui <- fluidPage(
          sidebarPanel(
            fluidRow(
              selectInput("INPUT",  label="Entrada:"  ,choices=list("",1,2,3,4,5,6,7)),
              selectInput("NOMEIPT", label="Nome:", choices=list("","Área","Comprimento","Largura")),
              selectInput("COLOUR", label="Cor:",  choices=list("","black","white","red","green","blue","brown","yellow")),
              actionButton("ADDIN",label="adicionar"))),
          mainPanel(fluidPage(
            fluidRow(tableOutput("dados")))))

## Única alterada por mim
server <- function(session,input, output) {

  ## Uso do reactvalues para armazenar os dados
  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = df)

  ## Sempre que houver um toque no botão uma nova linha é adicionada
  observeEvent(input$ADDIN, {
    nova_linha <- data.frame(Entrada=input$INPUT, Nome=input$NOMEIPT, Cor=input$COLOUR)
    values$df_data <- rbind(values$df_data, nova_linha)
  })

  output$dados<-renderTable({ values$df_data
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

o comportamento que você vai obter é como segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CONSIDERAÇÕES**

Do ponto de vista de programação web o problema que você está enfrentando é o problema de gerenciar o estado da aplicação. Veja que uma boa aplicação deve estar desacoplada dos dados. O **ideal** seria você criar uma forma de armazenar os dados necessários para selecionar os futuros arquivos que você vai baixar na própria seleção dos inputs  e não armazenar em um `data.frame`. A forma **ideal** de armazenar os dados do app ao longo das sessões é por meio de um sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados, que poderia ser até o SQLite3. Entretanto, nesse caso, os dados ficariam armazenados de forma permanente o que creio que não era seu objetivo. Não postei essa solução porque foge do escopo da pergunta e acredito que não seria a solução ideal para o seu problema.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Flavio Barros, me quebrou foi uma árvore!!!